# Why the width of grid system is more greater than body?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, material-design

First of all, my native language is not English I hope that question and description are clear. I'm sorry if they're not.

Problem:

I'm using MDB framework, when I use the grid system the width of the last column is more greater than body. I tried to put widht: 100%; in the content and in every column (Class: Nx).

How do I fix this?

Html:

```
<div class="Mycolumns">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-8 N1" style="background-image: url(Resources/img/1.jpg); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: cover;">

        </div>
        <div class="col-4 N2" style="background-image: url(Resources/img/Sin%20t%C3%ADtulo-1.jpg); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: cover;">

        </div>
        <div class="col-4 N3" style="background-image: url(Resources/img/3.jpg); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: cover;">

        </div>
        <div class="col-4 N4" style="background-image: url(Resources/img/4.jpg); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: cover;">

        </div>
        <div class="col-4 N5" style="background-image: url(Resources/img/5.jpg); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: cover;">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Css:

```
.N1, .N2{
height: 500px;
}

.N3, .N4, N5{
 height: 300px;
}
```

Comment: I already fixed it, I just had to add container-fluid to my first div

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered the same problem. What was doing it was one of my nested elements was set to width: 100vw - The view width seems to be the entire browser window *including* the scrollbar, so you effectively get '100% + scrollbar width' as your width, which gave me a 15px or so blowout. Changing the element's width to 100% fixed it.